# how can i make a slideshow for content loaded on pageload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slideshow

i want to make a slide show that will contain a two dashboards loaded on two  `Divs`.

```
<div id="chartContainer1"></div>
<div id="chartContainer2"></div>
```

i only have these two `Divs` and on page load i am making a `Json` call to get some data then using the `Chartjs` "a Jquery plugin" the dashboards got filled
so the question is how can i put these two dashboard in a slide show ?
here is my page code

```
 <div id="chartContainer1"></div>
    <div id="chartContainer2"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //var dataSource = $("#chartContainer").dxChart('option', 'dataSource', {});
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("StatesChart", "Home")',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                var array = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#chartContainer1").dxPieChart({
                    dataSource: array,
                    title: "",
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: "decimal",
                        percentPrecision: 2,
                        //the text that will be shown on hober on any part of the pie
                        customizeText: function() {
                            return this.valueText + " - " + this.percentText;
                        }
                    },
                    //right details
                    legend: {
                        horizontalAlignment: "right",
                        verticalAlignment: "top",
                        margin: 4
                    },
                    series: {
                        type: "doughnut",
                        argumentField: "StateName",
                        valueField: "AllAssetsNumber",
                        label: {
                            visible: true,
                            format: "decimal",
                            connector: {
                                visible: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Save Failure', "error");
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you write what you have already done ? Add some code, please.

Comment: there is no need to add code as what i want is to clear, Mr @kmas suppose that you have divs that just have texts how can we put these two divs in a slide show ? thx in advance

Comment: There are some many answers. That's why I'm asking some of your code.

Comment: thank you for your attention but actually there is no code will let you specify what i have but anyway i'll modify the question with my page code

Comment: so here is the code what do you see now !!??

Comment: @kmas man u kiddin me !!!! i told u that i want to make this slider to peview a div content not images !!!

Comment: Ho sorry, I have changed this one but I forget to save it : http://jsfiddle.net/xYWzU/234/